# Vagrant shared and synced folders

Tags: vagrant

I created a Vagrantfile with the following content:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|

  config.vm.define :foo do |cfg|
    cfg.vm.box     = 'foo'
    cfg.vm.host_name = "foo.localdomain.local"
    cfg.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.123.10"
  end

  Vagrant.configure("2") do |cfg|
    cfg.vm.customize [ "modifyvm", :id , "--name", "foo" , "--memory", "2048", "--cpus", "1"]
    cfg.vm.synced_folder "/tmp/", "/tmp/src/"
  end

end
```

After `vagrant up` or `vagrant reload` I get:

```
[foo] Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
[foo] Setting the name of the VM...
[foo] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[foo] Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
[foo] Creating shared folders metadata...
[foo] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[foo] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[foo] Forwarding ports...
[foo] -- 22 => 2200 (adapter 1)
[foo] Booting VM...
[foo] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[foo] VM booted and ready for use!
[foo] Setting hostname...
[foo] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
[foo] Mounting shared folders...
[foo] -- /vagrant
```

My questions are:

1. Why is Vagrant mounting the `/vagrant` shared folder? I read shared folders are deprecated in favour of synced folders, and I never defined any shared folder in my Vagrantfile.
2. Why is the synced folder not set up?

I'm using Vagrant version 1.2.7 on MacOX 10.8.4.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

#### shared folders VS synced folders

Basically shared folders are renamed to synced folder from v1 to v2 (docs), under the bonnet it is still using `vboxsf` between host and guest (there is known performance issues if there are large numbers of files/directories).

#### Vagrantfile directory mounted as `/vagrant` in guest

Vagrant is mounting the current working directory (where `Vagrantfile` resides) as `/vagrant` in the guest, this is the default behaviour.

See [docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/index.html)

> NOTE: By default, Vagrant will share your project directory (the directory with the Vagrantfile) to /vagrant.

You can disable this behaviour by adding `cfg.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true` in your `Vagrantfile`.

#### Why synced folder is not working

Based on the output `/tmp` on host was NOT mounted during up time.

Use `VAGRANT_INFO=debug vagrant up` or `VAGRANT_INFO=debug vagrant reload` to start the VM for more output regarding why the synced folder is not mounted. Could be a permission issue (mode bits of `/tmp` on host should be `drwxrwxrwt`).

I did a test quick test using the following and it worked (I used opscode bento raring vagrant base box)

`config.vm.synced_folder "/tmp", "/tmp/src"`

output

```
$ vagrant reload
[default] Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
[default] Setting the name of the VM...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Available bridged network interfaces:
1) eth0
2) vmnet8
3) lxcbr0
4) vmnet1
What interface should the network bridge to? 1
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] VM booted and ready for use!
[default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- /vagrant
[default] -- /tmp/src
```

Within the VM, you can see the mount info `/tmp/src on /tmp/src type vboxsf (uid=900,gid=900,rw)`.

Comment: `vagrant up --debug` or `vagrant reload --debug` might be usefull

Comment: cfg.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true to disable the default mount is very helpful, thanks

Comment: I had a host folder outside of the vm "public" folder, correctly set to sync, but it would not mount when the machine boot. The `VAGRANT_INFO=debug vagrant reload` did the trick for me and now it mounts every time. Thanks!

Comment: I had to add `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: false` to `Vagrantfile` to make it work. I guess the default has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: false
```

to `Vagrantfile` worked for me for a FreeBSD 13.1 guest provided by `bento/freebsd-13`.

The host was running macOS 12.5.1, Vagrant 2.3.0, and VirtualBox 6.2.36.