# config.vm.share_folder setting not found

Tags: settings, virtualbox, vagrant

I am getting this error with this line in my Vagrantfile during vagrant up, until I comment it out.

The setting is documented here:

http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/vm/share_folder.html

## Not sure why the following documented paramenter causes an error

`config.vm.share_folder "puppetdir", "/etc/puppet", "/vagrant/mypuppetdir"`

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The following settings don't exist: share_folder
```

The latest virtualbox and latest vagrant. everything else works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Vagrant 1.1+ you should use `config.vm.synced_folder`, the docs you are looking at are for older versions. Please refer to the updated documentation for more info: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html

Answer (score 1):

Shared Folders has been renamed to Synded Folder since 1.1.

In your `Vagrantfile` you should be using the following

```rb
  config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # by default enabled, uncomment to disable
  # config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
```

> NOTE: By default, Vagrant will share your project directory (the directory where `Vagrantfile` resides) to `/vagrant`.

```rb
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
```

More flexible example

```rb
  vagrant_data = File.expand_path("../vagrant_data", __FILE__)
  Dir::mkdir(vagrant_data) unless FileTest::directory?(vagrant_data)
  config.vm.synced_folder "vagrant_data", "/vagrant_data"
```

Take a look at this for more information => [shared folders VS synced folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528717/vagrant-shared-and-synced-folders/18529697)

Answer (score 0):

Extending from https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/936#issuecomment-7179034

if you need to mount a volume as a user that doesn't exist when the vm boots you can get there like so:

```
# Vagrantfile line

config.vm.synced_folder "host_folder", "/svr/fake_mount_folder", id: "whatever_name"
# ...
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  # ...
  # In my case a package installed a user with UID 110, GID 116
  mount -t vboxsf -o uid=110,gid=116 whatever_name /media/actual_mounted_folder
  # ...
SHELL
```