# How to share a folder created inside vagrant?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I have a vagrant VM and I have shared a folder (my code repo) from the host (Ubuntu) to vagrant using `config.vm.share_folder`. I would like to do the opposite with a folder I have created inside the vagrant machine (a virtual environment) I would like to share it back to the host. How can I do that?

I have tried to add the following to the vagrant file: `config.vm.share_folder "virtualenv", "/home/vagrant/devenv", "../virtualenv"` which points respectively to the virtual environment on the vagrant machine and to an empty folder on the host. When I vagrant up and look inside the folder on the host I would like to see the content of the virtual env inside the vagrant machine but the folder stays empty. And when I ssh into the vagrant machine and look inside the virtual env folder it has become empty. Deactivating this setting restores the content of the folder on the vagrant machine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### shared folders VS synced folders

Shared folders has been renamed to synced folders from v1 to v2 (docs), under the bonnet it is still using `vboxsf` between host and guest (there is known performance issues if there are large numbers of files/directories).

> **NOTE**: You need to understand it mounts host directory into the guest via `vboxsf`, **NOT** the other way around.

In your use case, you can

1. use synced folder to map folders between host and guest (suppose they both are empty), then within the guest, copy (`rsync` is preferred) or move the project into the mapped folder.
2. copy the contents from guest to host (using `scp` or `rsync`) folder
   A, and then use synced folder to map folder A on host into guest.

For example

```rb
# relative path to where Vagrantfile resides
config.vm.synced_folder "virtualenv", "/home/vagrant/devenv"

# absolute path
config.vm.synced_folder "/path/to/virtualenv", "/home/vagrant/devenv"
```

1. maps the virtualenv directory in the project directory (where the `Vagrantfile` resides) to guest `/home/vagrant/devenv`.
2. absolute path

More information that can help you understand how synced folders work `=>` [Vagrant shared and synced folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528717/vagrant-shared-and-synced-folders)

Answer (score 0):

In both shared folders and synced folders (see http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/ ) edits are going both ways. The host folder and Vagrant folder are always in sync. In other words, it is shared both ways, so you won't need to do anything.

Comment: I don't get it, if I add the line `config.vm.share_folder "virtualenv", "/home/vagrant/devenv", "../virtualenv"` which points respectively to my virtual environment on the vagrant machine and to an empty folder on the host, when I ssh into the machine and go to that folder it is empty, where normally there are all my files for the virtual env. The doc you point to explains how to share a folder from the host to the guest (even though edits are reflected both ways). I want the opposite, the content is on the guest and I want to mount it on the host. It does not seem to happen this way.

Comment: Check the permissions. Also, try the newer and more generic "Synced Folders" instead of "Shared folders"

Comment: Also, I believe the second parameter (path on the virtual environment) should be absolute, so the line should look something like:

`config.vm.share_folder "virtualenv", "/home/vagrant/devenv", "/path/to/virtualenv"`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shared folder in Vagrant with:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "data", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"]
```

Share Mac into Ubuntu path

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/Myname/www-vagrant", "/var/www/vagrant",
```

owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"

Comment: please also provide an explanation with your code. This will make your answer much more comprehensible.

Comment: Won't this delete everything in the sync folder in the vm?