# Vagrant: what is the difference between "shared" and "synced" directories?

Tags: share, synchronization, vagrant

Vagrant uses the words "share" and "sync" seemingly interchangeably. Is there a difference? If so, what is the difference?

IMO, "sync" implies that the data is duplicated in two places, and Vagrant does some magic to ensure that changes to one are also made to the other. This is a slightly different semantics to "sharing". Which is Vagrant doing, or can it do both?

**EDIT:** for example, say, I want a VM running MySQL server, but storing the database files on the host. Is this kind of setup the kind of thing that shared/syncd directories are appropriate for? E.g., do I have a guarantee of atomicity/transactionality? Sharing semantics would guarantee this, but syncing semantics possibly wouldn't.

(To make things worse, there's also [Vagrant Share](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/share/index.html), which is unrelated to syncing or sharing.)

Answer (score 1):

### shared folder (v1 terminology) VS synced folder (renamed in v2)

In short: **Shared Folders** is more VirtualBox specific (`vboxsf`) and have known performance issues as number of files grows.

Vagrant v2 (vagrant 1.1.x, 1.2.x +) docs use a more generic name called **Synced Folder**, which now includes many options: default `vboxsf`, `rsync`, samba/CIFS, NFS.

By default, vagrant sync the project directory (where `Vagrantfile` resides) with `/vagrant` within the guest. This can be disabled by explicitly disable it in `Vagnrantfile` and do a `vagrant reload`.

e.g. `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true`

To see a long story, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18529697/1801697

### Let's talk about **sync**

For `vboxsf` and `nfs`, host and guest folders (I mean synced folders) are always in sync (changes made on either side is synced to the other).

> NOTE: SMB/CIFS should be the same but I've never used it.

In vagrant 1.5, `rsync` type is added, which makes manual sync possible, by default it sync from host to guest upon 1st `vagrant up`. I personally prefer `rsync` if real-time sync between host and is **NOT** needed.

BTW: Vagrant share is something different, it's sharing SSH access or other services via a cloud gateway.