# Vagrant synced folders disappearing

Tags: vagrant

I'm using vagrant and have **hashicorp/precise32** box. My projects in **/products/** folder on this box. I want to reach this folder from my host computer. So added this configuration to my Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/products","/products"
```

Also created **/products** folder on host. But after reload when I connect to box over SSH, /products folder's all contents are disappearing. When I comment out the **config.vm.synced_folder** line and reload, contents appering again.

Can you please tell me what's I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Vagrant sync folder works the other way around

> Synced folders enable Vagrant to sync a folder on the host machine to
>   the guest machine, allowing you to continue working on your project's
>   files on your host machine, but use the resources in the guest machine
>   to compile or run your project.

so if you have an existing folder on your guest machine and you ask vagrant to create a sync folder with one of your folder from the host, it will do but replace the content from the content of your host.

There is an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528717/vagrant-shared-and-synced-folders) with some good reference to understand it further

Comment: Hello Frederic, thank you for your response. What you are suggesting me to reach my project files from host ? I tried creating a symbolic link from my products folder to /vagrant folder. Because /vagrant folder mounting to host automatically. But in host computer symlink not working.

Comment: Hi Eray, I am afraid its not possible (at least I do not know of a way) usually you would work from the host and deploy files on guest not the other way around - if you need to get back from files from your VM copy them to vagrant folder then you will access them

Comment: So I should transfer my project files to host machine and deploy on guest machine. Give me a few minutes I will try now :)